# Can not use method variables in Objective-C class' extension in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, extension-methods

```
class FirstTest {
    func testMe() {
        println("This is a simple test.")
    }
}

extension FirstTest {
    func output() {
        let myTestMe = testMe
        myTestMe()
    }
}

let myFirstTest = FirstTest()
myFirstTest.output()
//This is a simple test.
```

Above code works. However, if I make the class inherits NSObject, I will get below error.

```
class FirstTest: NSObject {
    func testMe() {
        println("This is a simple test.")
    }
}

extension FirstTest {
    func output() {
        let myTestMe = testMe
        myTestMe()
    }
}

let myFirstTest = FirstTest()
//objc[22959]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
//objc[22959]: receiver 0x10d62c980, SEL 0x1039021a5, isa 0x10d62ca20, cache 0x10d62ca30, buckets 0x7fc6a1d18d80, mask 0x0, occupied 0x0
//objc[22959]: receiver 0 bytes, buckets 64 bytes
//objc[22959]: selector 'allocWithZone:'
//objc[22959]: isa '__lldb_expr_1.FirstTest'
//objc[22959]: Method cache corrupted.
```

Someone may say it is because of a c pointer of something. However, if I put the code in extension back to the class, everything works fine again.

```
class FirstTest: NSObject {
    func testMe() {
        println("This is a simple test.")
    }

    func output() {
        let myTestMe = testMe
        myTestMe()
    }
}

let myFirstTest = FirstTest()
myFirstTest.output()
//This is a simple test.
```

All above codes are run in Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Comment: It seems my question is similar like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131121/declaring-conformance-to-objc-protocol-in-empty-extension-breaks-with-exc-bad-i

Comment: If I take your crashing code and compile it (after adding an import for Foundation) as-is with `swiftc`, it works fine – possibly something else you’re not showing is causing this problem indirectly.

Comment: You are right. Today Apple releases Xcode 6.3 beta, which include Swift 1.2. My above code runs successfully in Xcode 6.3 beta. Also my code failed in Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.2 beta. So it is a bug in current stable Xcode.